# Rechart Responsive container does not render

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Im trying to render a bar chart to fit 100% its container with reChart:

http://recharts.org/#/en-US/api/ResponsiveContainer

```
 <div className="question">
    <div className="question-container">
        <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height="100%">
            <BarChart   layout="vertical" data={rows}
                      margin={{top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5}}>

                <YAxis axisLine={false} tickLine={false} width={400} dataKey="name" type="category">
                </YAxis>
                <Bar dataKey="valuePre" fill="#00a0dc" label={<Text scaleToFit={true} verticalAnchor="middle" />}/>
                <Bar dataKey="valuePost" fill="#c7c7c7"  label={<Text verticalAnchor="middle" />}/>

            </BarChart>
        </ResponsiveContainer>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I add the ResponsiveContainer component, the data stops rendering. And as soon as I taker out the ResponsiveContainer and set the width and height of the BarChart component, I can see the bar chart again.

Can anyone help me spot what Im doing wrong?

Heres a fiddle with the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/eyh80eeo/

Comment: Take a look at your console, you have alot of uncaught references.

Comment: Apart from the answers below, make sure you supply the width and/or height with an integer instead of string like "100px". Why Re(act)charts decided to completely abandon Reacts idiomatic way of supplying widths and heights is beyond me.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Since `ResponsiveContainer` relies on the parent's dimensions you need to make sure the parent has a proper `width` and `height`.

The reason why a setting on `<Barchart />` works is because it sets its own `width` and `height`.

Check out this fiddle [**RESPONSIVECONTAINER**](http://jsfiddle.net/jgwyz0cr/1/)

I added CSS to the parent classes you have

```
.question {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

.question-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It worked great. I have another question, do you know why the second bar doesnt render? I just see the bar with value 3. The bar with value one does not show unless I set the value to 3 also.

Comment: You are welcome. Regarding this I won't be able to check now as I am out. Both bars seem to appear when `preValue` and `postValue` are equal. I would suggest you to post another question if it's urgent and leave a link here just in case.

Comment: 99% of the times the problem in only with the `height`, so make `height=300` and leave `width="100%"`

Answer (score 26):

I had a similar issue when using the **ResponsiveContainer** component, within a CSS grid.

I simply added `width={'99%'}` to the **ResponsiveContainer** and it resized correctly.

`<ResponsiveContainer width={'99%'} height={300}>`

Reference: [Recharts Responsive Chart not responsive inside a CSS grid](https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/1423)

Comment: Excellent! Exactly what I needed :) Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

give a fixed height for responsive container

```
<ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height={400}>
        <BarChart   layout="vertical" data={rows}
                  margin={{top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5}}>

            <YAxis axisLine={false} tickLine={false} width={400} dataKey="name" type="category">
            </YAxis>
            <Bar dataKey="valuePre" fill="#00a0dc" label={<Text scaleToFit={true} verticalAnchor="middle" />}/>
            <Bar dataKey="valuePost" fill="#c7c7c7"  label={<Text verticalAnchor="middle" />}/>

        </BarChart>
    </ResponsiveContainer>
```

Answer (score 14):

I wasn't able to set a height for my container, so I used `aspect`, which sets the height of the ResponsiveContainer:

```
 <ResponsiveContainer width={"100%"} aspect={1}>
```

Comment: Exactly solved my problems :)

Comment: Halleluijah. This finally worked for me after struggling with this component inside a CSS grid.

Answer (score 2):

For anybody rendering the chart inside a `react-bootstrap` component, don't use the `ResponsiveContainer` tag. you can simple use the logic inside of it and it will run. Asumming you use `react-bootstrap` it would look like this:

```
<div className="question">
<div className="question-container">
        <BarChart   layout="vertical" data={rows}
                  margin={{top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5}}>

            <YAxis axisLine={false} tickLine={false} width={400} dataKey="name" type="category">
            </YAxis>
            <Bar dataKey="valuePre" fill="#00a0dc" label={<Text scaleToFit={true} verticalAnchor="middle" />}/>
            <Bar dataKey="valuePost" fill="#c7c7c7"  label={<Text verticalAnchor="middle" />}/>

        </BarChart>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding an information as I was struggling with it too.

As it was said before, the parent needs to have a proper height and width.

Not min-height, not height with a percent, not relying only on flex-grow.

For my case, the answer was to set height to an absolute value, and then to use flex-grow to adapt the height according to the space available.
Hope that help someone else.